# Phpmyadmin 4.8.2 Relation view 500 error

Tags: phpmyadmin

It happens after update to 4.8.2 and happens for any database and any table
[image]

Have error message in http response, but sorry - it is unformated

```
<div class=\"notice\"><strong>Deprecation Notice<\/strong> in .\/..\/..\/..\/..\/..\/..\/var\/lib\/phpMyAdmin\/temp\/twig\/5a\/5ac52eca2b921b321588ffc83fbbb680b9169ee67cd2feef47f39e5ac2a8972c.php#384<br \/>\n<img src=\"themes\/dot.gif\" title=\"\" alt=\"\" class=\"icon ic_s_notice\" \/> Non-static method PhpMyAdmin\\Relation::getDisplayField() should not be called statically<br \/>\n<br \/>\n<strong>Backtrace<\/strong><br \/>\n<br \/>\nTemplate.php#432: __TwigTemplate_2b0a992f522826ef7b64d82b32d6dd48f61ee2c88cf90a2a8b997980d6e8d0ee->doDisplay(<br \/>\n\tarray,<br \/>\n\tarray,<br \/>\n)<br \/>\nTemplate.php#403: Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(<br \/>\n\tarray,<br \/>\n\tarray,<br \/>\n)<br \/>\nTemplate.php#411: Twig_Template->display(array)<br \/>\nTemplateWrapper.php#43: Twig_Template->render(array)<br \/>\n.\/libraries\/classes\/Template.php#133: Twig_TemplateWrapper->render(array)<br \/>\n.\/libraries\/classes\/Controllers\/Table\/TableRelationController.php#207: PhpMyAdmin\\Template->render(array)<br \/>\n.\/tbl_relation.php#71: PhpMyAdmin\\Controllers\\Table\\TableRelationController->indexAction()<br \/>\n<\/div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was conflict with some old temporary files. Just clear them:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/phpMyAdmin/temp
```